# LLVM still and will not support for static link openmp?

Tags: linker, clang, openmp, llvm

every one.

I am curious about did clang can't static link the openmp library when compliling. When i try to build spec2017 intspeed benchmarks, I found when i try to build them staticly, will failed with error `cannot find -lomp`.

```
  /usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/clang -m64  -z muldefs     -pthread -static    -DSPEC_LINUX_X64   -DSPEC_OPENMP -fopenmp -Wno  -return-type -DUSE_OPENMP -I /usr/lib/lib/libomp_oss/exports/common/include  av.o caretx.o deb.o doio.o doop.o dum  p.o globals.o gv.o hv.o keywords.o locale.o mg.o numeric.o op.o pad.o perl.o perlapi.o perlio.o perlmain.o perly.o   pp.o pp_ctl.o pp_hot.o pp_pack.o pp_sort.o pp_sys.o regcomp.o regexec.o run.o scope.o sv.o taint.o toke.o univers  al.o utf8.o util.o reentr.o mro_core.o mathoms.o specrand/specrand.o dist/PathTools/Cwd.o dist/Data-Dumper/Dumper.  o ext/Devel-Peek/Peek.o cpan/Digest-MD5/MD5.o cpan/Digest-SHA/SHA.o DynaLoader.o dist/IO/IO.o dist/IO/poll.o cpan/  MIME-Base64/Base64.o Opcode.o dist/Storable/Storable.o ext/Sys-Hostname/Hostname.o cpan/Time-HiRes/HiRes.o ext/XS-  Typemap/stdio.o ext/attributes/attributes.o cpan/HTML-Parser/Parser.o ext/mro/mro.o ext/re/re.o ext/re/re_comp.o e  xt/re/re_exec.o ext/arybase/arybase.o ext/PerlIO-scalar/scalar.o ext/PerlIO-via/via.o ext/File-Glob/bsd_glob.o ext  /File-Glob/Glob.o ext/Hash-Util/Util.o ext/Hash-Util-FieldHash/FieldHash.o ext/Tie-Hash-NamedCapture/NamedCapture.  o cpan/Scalar-List-Utils/ListUtil.o             -lm     -fopenmp -L/usr/lib/lib/libomp_oss/exports/lin_32e/lib      -o perlbench_s
  /usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find -lomp
```

So, i searched the llvm lib for omp, only find libomp.so, but no omp realated `.a` file. Then found the posted mail of wheather need static openmp library, seem like LLVM developers reject this opinion.
https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/openmp-dev/2016-January/001051.html

Did i miss something, or is there someway can link openmp staticly i not found?

Thanks for your suggestions.

I did build those spec benchmarks use llvm10 and llvm15 with dynamic link on ubuntu20.04, all found the -lomp, build successfully.

Comment: I share the point of view of LLVM developers. There are few other issues related to the use of an OpenMP static library like increasing the size of the target executable, causing maintenance issues, not to mention it will certainly *not* improve the performance in well-designed OpenMP applications. Why do you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: @Jérôme Richard
Most for Portability, if i want to test those benchmark in a meachine which do not have the develope enviroment, not have the dynamic openmp lib. It would be helpful to staticly build those benchmarks in develope server, then just copy them into test meachine.